# Set of Elements is Element of a Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given:

$A =\{x ∈ Z:$ x is an integer multiple of 3 $\}$

$E = \{ 3, 6, 9 \}$

Is $\{3, 6, 9\} \in A$?

I don't think it is because the entire set is not an element of $A$, but I have seen conflicting answers so I am unsure. I don't think it is the same as saying $3∈A$, $6∈A$, $9∈A$.

What about E ∈ A?

Comment: You need to put \ before the brackets for them to show up.  I'll fix it for you....

Comment: sorry and thank you

Comment: You are correct.  $\{3,6,9\} \subset A$ but $\{3,6,9\} \not \in A$.  ANd as $E = \{3,6,9\}$ the same is true of $E$.

Comment: Hmmmm.... there is some shorthand that it somethimes done such as:  If $x^2 -x - 6 = 0$ then $x =\{3,-2\}$-- is sometimes written to mean $x =3$ or $x =-2$ or $x \in \{3,-2\}$.  This is actually *wrong* but people often write it for shorthand.  If we squint real hard  and say "well, we can write '$\{1,3,5,15\}|15$' to means $1,3,5,15$ are numbers that divide $15$ then maybe we can say '$\{3,6,9\}\in A$' means $3,6,9$ are three elements in A"... But that'd be wrong and should be nipped in the bud.... but... maybe somehere there is someone who did that.

Comment: Can you cite one of the conflicting answers?  .... it seems to me you understand the important concept.  Although $3,6,$ and $9$ are each elements in $A$, However the SET of $\{3,6,9\}$ is NOT an element of $A$ and subsets are not elements, and if a *set* **is** an element of a set, that does not mean it is a subset.  If you have that clear that is good... but I'm curious about the conflicting answers.

Comment: It was a few answers on Chegg, you probably need an account to view it but here: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/use-definitions-sets-given-determine-whether-statement-true-false-x-z-x-integer-multiple-3-q24200647

Comment: The answer that is there is : "(g) This statement is TRUE as E={3,6,9} which definitely belongs to the element A={3,6,9,12....}" . I trust my own knowledge, but this really caused some confusion for me.

Comment: That answer sounds like it was written by a student who is trying but struggling with concept of a set vs an element and is confused about the ambiguity of the *NON*mathematical word "contained".  That answer is wrong. You appear to understand the concept clearly and you are correct.  $E=\{3,6,9\}$ is a set, the elements of which are each contained as elements in the *set* of $A$ but the set $E$ itself is *not* an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right. $ E \in A $ means E is element of A which is not true. On the other hand E is a subset of A: $ E \subset A $